# How print each smaller dictionary in new line in nested dictionary

Tags: python

I wrote a nested dictionary program. The dictionary generates well but I would like every smaller dictionary to be printed in a new line.

```
      import random

list_of_surname = ["Gates", "Bezos", "Buffett", "Zuckerberg", "Arnault", 
"Page", "Sołowow", "Solorz"]

list_of_name = ["Bill", "Jeff", "Warren ", "Mark ", "Bernard", "Larry ",
 "Michał", "Zygmunt"]

list_of_age = [73, 24, 35, 76, 64, 75, 86, 45]

list_of_profession = ["businessman", "chairman", "inventor", "pioneer", 
 "speculator", "programmer"]

def generator_of_random_nested_dictionary(number_of_dictionaries):
    nested_dictionary = {f'person_{number_of_dictionaries}' :
    {"surname":random.choice(list_of_surname),
     "name":random.choice(list_of_name),
     "age":random.choice(list_of_age),
     "profession":random.choice(list_of_profession)} 
     for number_of_dictionaries in range (1,number_of_dictionaries+1)}
    print("")
    print ([(x,y)for x,y in nested_dictionary.items()],sep="\n")
    print("")    
    '''
    print((for key,values in nested_dictionary,sep="\n"))
    '''
generator_of_random_nested_dictionary(3)
```

this is my output:

```
[('person_1', {'surname': 'Arnault', 'name': 'Larry ', 'age': 24, 'profession': 'inventor'}), ('person_2', {'surname': 'Arnault', 'name': 'Larry ', 'age': 35, 'profession': 'businessman'}), ('person_3', {'surname': 'Solorz', 'name': 'Michał', 'age': 76, 'profession': 'pioneer'})]
```

output is good but how to modify the print function so that each smaller dictionary is displayed in a new line? I would like to have output in this form:

```
[('person_1', {'surname': 'Arnault', 'name': 'Larry ', 'age': 24, 'profession': 'inventor'}),
('person_2', {'surname': 'Arnault', 'name': 'Larry ', 'age': 35, 'profession': 'businessman'}),
('person_3', {'surname': 'Solorz', 'name': 'Michał', 'age': 76, 'profession': 'pioneer'})]
```

Comment: You could use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module

Answer (score 1):

Passing a list to print isn't doing what you want:

```
print ([(x,y)for x,y in nested_dictionary.items()],sep="\n")
```

To use the `sep` argument to `print`, you need to pass the elements of this list as separate arguments, which we can do with the `*` operator:

```
print (*[(x,y)for x,y in nested_dictionary.items()],sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

importing the pprint module and changing the line to this:

```
pprint.pprint([(x,y)for x,y in nested_dictionary.items()], width=100)
```

Did the work for me.